# Duplicidad al imprimir tickets php mysql jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, print

Estoy desarrollando un punto de venta con php mysql y jquery, hasta hace unos dias todo iba bien, pero desde hace unos dias me duplica los tickets.
Estando en la ventana de captura de articulos presionando F5 abro una ventana para capturar la cantidad de efectivo con el que pagará el cliente.
De ahi abro otra ventana con el contenido del ticket y lo mando imroimir con:

```
window.onload = function () { 
  window.print();
  open(location, '_self').close();
}
```

Funcionaba muy bien pero, ahora sale 1 solo ticket pero me duplica los tickets en la base de datos es decir si sale el ticket 450, en la base tengo el 450 y el 451 por la misma cantidad.

Comment: Por favor publicá el código PHP.

Comment: Que tal geosilva... bienvenido. Te recomiendo hagas un [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También seria bueno que te des una vuelta por [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta.